# Time based log level

Tags: java, logging, logback

For one specific logger, I need to have info level logging during 9 to 5 but warning level after that. Can someone help me with logback configuration for something like this?

I couldn't find any time based log level configuration anywhere.

Comment: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#JaninoEventEvaluator